# Change Git Roots in Android Studio

Tags: git, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I have a Android git project with multiple git submodules.
For some reason, the Android Studio git integration selected the root to be one of the submodules, so I can't see my changes in the "Version Control" pane. 
Any idea how to modify the git roots of a project?

I saw this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-cvs-roots.html, but I don't have the VCS Roots window in Android studio.

Answer (score 8):

Finally found it!

(I'm working on Mac)
In the menu, click **Android Studio** -> **Preferences** -> **Version Control** tab.
There you can control the version control roots.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me delete an incorrect git root that was messing up the git integration "commit", https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725690/android-studios-git-commit-not-seeing-my-modified-files/61726237